# Stuck during installation of Fredhopper 7.5 for 2014 SmartTarget 2014 upgrade

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, installation

I'm going through the installation guide to upgrade an old version of smarttarget to 2014 and i'm stuck at step 10. on this page : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SmartTarget%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D6FBA58F-BA63-4A73-BF81-3595EE47752E (log in required)

To quote the steps:

> Import the instance configuration: On Windows, run the following
>   command: bin\capture-import  /SmartTarget_upgrade.zip

My indexer is called '**SmartTarget**' and my back up zip is called '**st.zip**'

So I'm running:

capture-import SmartTarget D:/temp_st/st.zip

and I receive the error 'The system cannot find the specified path'

I've tried every combination I can think of, such as:

- Adding quotes to the file name
- Using '-'as my indexer name
- Removing the underscore from my path
- Ensuring 'Everyone' has access to the folder / file

Has anyone any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Could you try compressing this file(i assume its zipped by you) with other tool(winzip), sometime compression methods are not supported. 2) another try could be using another slash d:\temp_st\st.zip

Comment: Are you running this inside the bin folder?

Comment: yeah i'm running from the bin folder @Neil - thanks

Comment: @RajKumar yeah i've tried that too - no such luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `capture-import` command (and pretty much all other commands!) should be run  from the fredhopper installation directory, not from the `bin` directory.